# create a class method outside of class

Tags: php

is there a way to create a class method for a class from another class?

Example:

```
class A
{
    public function makeMethod()
    {
        $this->b = new B();
        //create a method for class B such as a __call() method
        //to catch an error trying to access a non existant class B method
        if (!method_exists($this->b, "__call")
            // create __call() method
    }
}

class B
{

}
```

Comment: Can I ask why you want to create methods for a class?

Comment: im making my own framework and am calling an applications controller from within another class. but i want to do something like my edit

Comment: Why not define the method inside your controller's definition... ?

Comment: good question! but i want everything to be as automated as possible system side. but also give the user the ability to overwrite default methods given to each application if they specify those methods themselves

Comment: You can use extend if you want to override base class' method, how familiar are you with the concept of OOP?

Comment: Then you want your user to `extend` your default classes, not add methods to empty user classes after the fact.

Comment: yes and no, they extend the system controller class but can also overwrite my default methods when they define those methods in their application controller themselves

Comment: @Eli Yes, so? Sounds like you're asking for standard OOP inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this example :

```
class A
{
    public function makeMethod()
    {
        $this->b = new B();
        //create a method for class B such as a __call() method
        //to catch an error trying to access a non existant class B method

        $this->b->doit();
    }
}

class B
{

    public function __call($name,$args)
    {
        echo "function called: $name with arguments: $args";
    }

}

$a = new A();

$a->makeMethod();

?>
```

This will output :

```
function called: doit with arguments: Array
```

---

So, in a way, we called a non-existant function of `class B` and we still can do something with that.... e.g. in your `__call` method in `class B` couldn't you point the execution to some callback function (even of `class A`)? Why "create" it? (Don't think from the developer's point of view, unless you absolutely have to... :-))

Just an idea...

---

A glimpse from Page/Module Execution handling in [Minima Framework](http://sourceforge.net/projects/minima/)  :

```
public function  __call($name, $arguments=NULL)
{
    $function_name = "_".$name;

    $trace = debug_backtrace();

    $moduleCall = false;

    if (isset($trace[2]))
    {

        if (isset($trace[2]['object']))
        {
        $trace = $trace[2]['object'];

        if (is_subclass_of($trace, 'mmModule'))
            $moduleCall = true;
        }
    }

    $args = $this->matchArguments($name, $arguments);

    if ($moduleCall) { $this->redirect ($name, $arguments); }
    else
    {
        $this->Result = call_user_func_array(array($this, $function_name), $args);

        $this->loadTemplate($name);
    }
}
```

***P.S.** Simply because I've already created a 100% PHP framework myself, and perhaps I know what you might need...*

Comment: I understand what you provided, but i want to create the __call() method from the system controller and inject it into the application controller. "magically" if i say create the __call() method myself then it will be cancel out the `if method_exists()`

Comment: @Eli Why not have the `__call` method there ready to process any call? (I'm attaching to my main answer a portion of my Module execution routine in my framework...)

Comment: heh, there are 1,000,000 ways to do something. My code is a tad bit different for loading modules =)

Comment: @Eli Well, obviously... I'm not saying my approach is the best; at least, that was what I had in mind in terms of implementing MY ideal framework... Of course, what you refer to as modules, or whatever MVC pattern you may have implemented, is probably a matter of definition... and taste. Btw, good luck with the project! (it's definitely a very very interesting journey! ;-))

Comment: @Eli Btw, I got it from the very first time I read your question : such questions either come from absolute novices confused with what they have in mind and how to solve it, or people involved in something really complicated... :-)

Comment: I'm obsessed with simplicity and want to have a fully automated system where making a new application would only take a few lines of code haha.

Comment: @Eli Well that's an interesting starting point. Mine was quite along the same lines : just describe what your website should have in a YAML file (database with tables, etc + pages with parameters + modules) and it creates it for you. :-) Well, quite... lol

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure you can actually create methods for a class on the fly. And if you can, I believe that would be very BAD OOP practice.

A class is essentially a blue print for an object. I can't see why you can't code the methods inside the class.

To stop errors on a controller that might not exist (ie: edit/), I use the following myself for my own MVC framework to check if a method exists in a class:

```
$controller = new $class();

if( method_exists( $controller, $this->uri['method'] ) )
    $controller->{$this->uri['method']}( $this->uri['var'] );
else
    $controller->index();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a method abstract in the superclass.  This means that a subclass is expected to implement the abstract method, but that no actual implementation will be provided.

If you declare a method abstract, then the class also has to be abstract.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
class A {

    public function makeMethod() {
        $this->b = new B ();
        // create a method for class B such as a __call() method
        // to catch an error trying to access a non existant class B method
    }

    public function __call($method, $args) {
        if (isset ( $this->$method )) {
            $func = $this->$method;
            $func ();
        }
    }
}

$foo = new A ();
$foo->baba = function () {
    echo "Hello Baba";
};

$foo->baba ();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the [runkit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php) extension installed, then there's a [runkit_method_add](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-method-add.php) feature there.... but this is rarely installed, and shouldn't be used arbitrarily.